# Prepending by element or array in addition

Tags: vhdl

I can't figure out why these two writings in VHDL have the same meaning:

```
("0" & x) + y
```

and `('0' & x) + ('0' & y)` given that we've declared in the entity

```
x,y : in unsigned(3 downto 0);
```

What is the difference between `"0" & x` and `'0' & x`?
Also why should we create so difficults adders in VHDL using logical functions and carries given that it is enough to simply write `x + y`(including one additional bit for the carry)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2 cases:

- `"0" & x`: Prepends an array with a single element of `'0'` to `x`
- `'0' & x`: Prepends a single element `'0'` to `x`

The result in both cases is `'x'` prepended with a single element of `'0'`.

Prepending a `'0'` is only required if the destination is longer than any of the two sources, `x` and `y`, since `x + y` will have the length of the longest of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Ok, but what is the type of x and y? Are they arrays or they are elements?
In my view they are both arrays of 4 elements but then why the second writing is correct(given that the second case is for element and not for an array)?

Comment: The `unsigned` type is effectively an array of the `std_logic` type, and in this case an array with 4 elements in range 3 downto 0.  The second writing works since VHDL define concatenated (`&`) for both arguments as element type of the other operand, as well as 1-D array that is used in the first writing.

Comment: The `&` operators are predefined for any single dimensional array type for any combination of element or array input. See IEEE 1076-2005 9.2.5 Adding operators. Character literals and string literals are converted to element values and arrays of element values by basic operation (5. Types, 5.1 General), the array type determined by context (9.3.2 Literals),  character literal type by overload resolution depending on context (5.2.2 Enumeration literals, 5.2.2.1 General, - see paragraph 6 particularly, 4.5 Subprogram overloading).